# How to sync reading list from iPhone to mac without iCloud

Tags: iphone, mac, safari, reading-list

I have lots of links in safari reading list on my iPhone and I want to sync it all with safari on my mac but without using iCloud. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to sync your Safari Reading List without iCloud. However iCloud is a free service, I would suggest just signing up for it.

Alternatively you could use another reading list service like Readability etc.. but they all work via a online service.